# How can I create a variable which changes in function of the clicked item?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having an issue on a C# WPF code : I have multiple colored images on a window and when I click on it, it becomes blurred (this works). But my code is really bad optimized and I would like to get some help !

Here's a small part of my code :

```
private void BrownBlur(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   Brown.BlurApply(blurRadius: 15, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), TimeSpan.Zero);
}

private void LightGreenBlur(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   LightGreen.BlurApply(blurRadius: 15, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), TimeSpan.Zero);
}
```

*And it goes like this for every color of the window...*

I know that this is probably the worst way to code something, so I tried things like this :

```
private void isBlurred()
{
   this.BlurApply(blurRadius: 15, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), TimeSpan.Zero);
}
```

But this is the whole window that becomes blurred...

So I'm asking you guys if you know an alternative to "this.BlurApply" or if you know a way to create a variable which changes in function of the clicked item !

Comment: The `sender` in the method signature `object sender` is "the thing that was clicked". Can you simply get its color and blur that? Or use it to look up whatever LightGreen is? Or put all the things in your window in a collection (like dictionary) and map from your thing (sender) to whatever it is you're blurring

Comment: The easiest way for me is indeed to get the color of the picture. How could I get its color in a variable like `currentImage` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One event for all your senders

```
private void OnBlureObjClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{ 
  UIElement obj = sender as UIElement; //other parent class or interface
  obj.BlurApply(blurRadius: 15, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), TimeSpan.Zero);
}
```

Then assign event to all your objets

```
Brand.OnMouseButtonClik +=OnBlureObjClick;
LightGreen.OnMouseButtonClik +=OnBlureObjClick;
```

Or create collection of your objects and than add event in foreach loop

```
foreach(var item in collection)
{
 item .OnMouseButtonClik +=OnBlureObjClick;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! It worked fine, I will now try to find out more about UIElement :) Thank you very much !